# Android app with HTML5

Tags: android, html, apk

I want to create a Android Application.
Altough I want to use HTML5 for creating that application.
Later on I even want to get the application to multiple platforms like for Apple.

I have tried Eclipse but couldn't get it to work.
When I create a new "Project > Web > Dynamic Web Project" I can't export this into a Android Application.

PhoneGap looks interesting.
Although I'm not sure how you can create a .apk (for android) there.
Or should this work together with Eclipse?

Could anybody give me a headstart?

- What Application should I use to make a HTML application?
- How do I create a .apk file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please go through following link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to dive right into developing with Phonegap, you can try out Telerik's AppBuilder (http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder). The demo project uses KendoUI Mobile (which I can also recommend) is comprehensive enough for anyone. As far as I recall you can use it for free for up to 2 projects.

There is also Intel's XDK (http://xdk-software.intel.com/), which is completely free - but the simulator and deployment features aren't as far developed as Telerik AppBuilder's are.

I strongly recommend AGAINST doing it the "real way" with eclipse/xcode if you have no prior experience with developing native android/iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following project:

http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

This will give you a good start. You can download it and import it into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap does create an APK.

Essentially what Phonegap does is present a WebView and a simple API for calling native methods on the respective platforms.  This allows you to write the same app and deploy it on multiple platforms with minimal or no changes.  The majority of what you would do in Phonegap is set up the projects to pull in the cross-platform libraries.

The major limitations come from lack of access to native UI components.  As you progress in app development you may find that it's a significant limitation.  I rarely build HTML5-based UIs anymore, and instead go with native apps.

There are other cross-platform frameworks out there as well.  Here's an article describing some pros and cons of each:

http://www.developereconomics.com/pros-cons-top-5-cross-platform-tools/